# My username mentioned twice in who command

Tags: linux, users, who

I noticed by chance today that I had 2 users running on my Linux system.

I do not know much about Linux users but I ended up running the “w” command that gave the following output when Firefox is running:

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
main     seat0    login-           17:22    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session --register-session gnome-session
main     tty2     tty2             17:22    8:01   2:50   0.21s /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 28 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 30120 -prefMapSiz
```

I would like to ask the following:

- Is it ok to have my username being mentioned twice? IE this is not a hack into my system or anything?
- I assume “/gdm-wayland-session --register-session gnome-session” represents me logged into Rocky and this is normal - is this correct?
- I dont understand why there would be a second instance of my username associated with “/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox” - I would assume there would be a single user “main” that is running firefox, not firefox running as second instance of my user name. Is this ok / normal? Is there anything to be concerned about here?

Thanks ahead of time…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal.

The seat is all of the hardware devices that are in your workspace which is in your case, is `seat0` as you are logged into a Gnome session whereas `tty2` or the terminal is what is being used to run `firefox`. In your case `tty2` is attached to `seat0`. If you were to log in via SSH, there would just be `pts/0` (assuming that it was only you who had logged in) and no seat because pts doesn't have one.